# Cannot load reviews on Google Play

Tags: android

When trying to see reviews for one of my apps published on Google Play, I am getting the error "**Loading reviews for your application failed. Please try again later. (500000)**" in developer console.
Doing the same for another app works as expected.

I tried to logout/login but without success.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the same problem and I've had it for quite some time. It comes and it goes.

Comment: I've received an answer from Google Play Team - "We are working on resolving this problem.". Hopefully it will be fixed soon

Answer (score 4):

From their [known issues page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2922603?hl=en):

> **Google Play Android Developer Known Issues**
>
> Welcome to the Google Play Known Issues page for Android developers.
>   Use the list below to find out if your problem is a known issue. If
>   the problem is listed here, we’re aware of it and are working to fix
>   it as soon as possible. By clicking on an issue, you can learn more
>   and let us know that you're affected.
>
> If you're experiencing an issue that is not listed here, please report
>   it by submitting a bug report [here](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/request.py?&contact_type=bugs).

In your case, your problem is not in their list of known issues, so I would [submit](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/request.py?&contact_type=bugs) a bug report if "try[ing] again later" (a day or two later) doesn't solve the problem.

Also, I'd try accessing the reviews page in question through Google Play (instead of through the developer console). If it works in one, but not in the other, then you've narrowed down the problem even more for their first level staff.

For the record, I don't have this problem for any of my apps, I just checked. In your case, it's weird that it would only do this for one app and not another. Perhaps, you got that error when they were doing some kind of BigTable maintenance/backups, and the glitch might go away soon. Perhaps, it could just be a value pair record that's corrupted with a weird character. Only they will be able to tell you what happened.

Expect a three business day turnaround for getting an initial response back. That's what I got the last time I submitted a developer account issue a few months ago. And the response wasn't automated, nor in a template format, their support person really did go in the system and solve my problem before replying to me.

Comment: Thanks, I have just submitted a bug report

Answer (score 0):

First, try [clearing your browser's cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache) and restart your browser.

If that doesn't fix the problem, you might want to try another browser, like Firefox if you use Google Chrome or Chrome if you're using Firefox.